# Fading text within a slider

Tags: jquery, slider, fadein, fadeout, scrollto

I'm currently working on a jquery slider that utilizes scrollTo.  Ideally I'd like the text on the left portion of the slider to fade in after the scrollTo animation occurs, with first the heading fading in, then the slug, then the button.  I'd also like to learn how to apply animation to the image after it's been "scrolled to" as well!

My lil beta can be seen here: http://towerwebstudio.com/GFC2/

Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 2):

Make the text and image display:none and then use the onAfter: setting of scrollTo to run the fadeIn function on both the image and the text:

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

make sure you hide the image and the text after they are scrolled out of view also.